# Java returning object

Tags: java, arrays, object, return

I'm creating a program that makes and modifies integer sets

Here is my code:

```
public class IntSet{
    private final int MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE=2000;
    private boolean [] data = new boolean[MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE+1];

    public IntSet(int... elts) {
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < elts.length; iteration++) {
            if(elts[iteration] <= MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE)
            data[elts[iteration]] = true;
        }
    }

    public IntSet(IntSet source){
        System.arraycopy(source.data, 0, this.data, 0, MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE);
    }
    public void setTo(IntSet source){
        System.arraycopy(source.data, 0, this.data, 0, MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE);
    }
    public void insertElement(int element){
        data[element] = true;
    }
    public void deleteElement(int element){
        data[element] = false;
}
    public boolean hasElement(int element){
        if(data[element] == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public boolean equals(IntSet other){
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
            if(data[iteration] == other.data[iteration]) {

            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String output = "{";
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
            if(data[iteration] == true)
                output += (iteration + ", ");
        }
        output += "}";
        return output;
    }
```

I'm struggling with my subtract function: The subtract function forms a new set that is equal to the first set, except that any element from the second set is removed. I know to I need to return an object, but I'm not sure how to. Any help is appreciated.

```
    public IntSet subtract(IntSet other) {
        for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
            if(data[iteration] == true && other.data[iteration] == true) {
                other.data[iteration] = false;
            }
            if(data[iteration] == true && other.data[iteration] == false) {
                other.data[iteration] = true;
            }
        }
        System.arraycopy(other.data, 0, this.data, 0, MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE);
    }
    public int getUpperLimit(){
        return MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may be asking for homework help.  While we have no issues with that per se, please observe these [dos and don'ts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/338845#338845), and edit your question accordingly.  (Even if this isn't homework, please consider the advice anyway.)

Comment: Thank you! I still personally believe I'm not violating any rules or anything. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Are you tryiing to store a set of integers? If so, where are you planning to store it? You are using an array of `boolean`. Why?

Comment: Never mind, I understood your logic, but I don't understand the reason.. But it's very "different"..

Comment: I am storing them in objects in another file like this`is2 = new IntSet(1,2,5);` The integer set's values range from 0 to 2000, which is why I am actually using the indexes of the boolean array. Let's say I have a set {1,2,3} I set data[1], data[2], and data[3] equal to true. I might call the subtract function like this: `is3.setTo(is3.subtract(is1))`

Comment: So you must create a copy of your set (you already have a constructor to do that), and then remove every element of the second set from this copy (and you also have a method to remove an element from a set).

Comment: Your `equals` method does not override `Object#equals`. If you intend it to then fix the signature and override `hashCode` to be consistent with it. If you don't intend it to, then change the name of your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your subtract method can be implemented like this:

1. Create a copy of your current object. Call this `newSet`.
2. If `other` set contains an element, set that `newSet` element to `false`, which essentially "removes" that element from `newSet`.
3. Return `newSet`.

The code would be like this:

---

```
public IntSet subtract(IntSet other) {
    IntSet newSet = new IntSet (this);
    for(int iteration = 0; iteration < MAXALLOWEDSETVALUE; iteration++) {
        if(other.data[iteration]) {
            newSet.data[iteration] = false;
        }
    }
    return newSet;
}
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool so I can create another object just while I'm in that function? That's pretty awesome

Comment: @T.Dog yes. You could also make changes to the same object you're at, and finish with `return this`.

Comment: The body of the loop could be reduced to `if (other.data[iteration]) { newSet.data[iteration] = false; }`

Comment: @JBNizet, Updated the answer per you comment. Thanks!